# Error RIME Address

Tags: tcp, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I am working on feedback loop to test RIME using Gnuradio companion.

when I give 
    `nc localhost 52001` 
in one terminal and 
    `nc localhost 52002` 
in another and type message, then I see the error like this

```
Warning: invalid target RIME-Address for unicast on channel 130. 
Message will not be sent.`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A RIME unicast "socket" is not associated with one particular endpoint. So a unicast packet has to be prefixed with the RIME address of the destination node.
For loopback testing with the default configuration try something like:

```
nc -u localhost 52001
23.42 Hello World!
```